# How Would I turn a dictionary with values of integers into a dictionary with values of lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, integer, iteration

I'm Trying to create a program and need help turning a dictionary with string keys and integer values into the same list but with list values. For Example:

```
dictionary = {"AAPL": 1000, "MSFT": 2000, "TSLA": 1500}
#Somehow turn this dictionary into this:
dictionary = {"AAPL": [1000], "MSFT": [2000], "TSLA": [1500]}
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Id then eventually add values to specific key pairs to get something like this:

```
dictionary = {"AAPL": [1000, 1100], "MSFT": [2000, 2400], "TSLA": [1500, 1450]}
```

I am using Python btw. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary comprehension and simply put the value inside a list literal.

```
dictionary = {key: [value] for key, value in dictionary.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k,v in dictionary.items():
    dictionary[k]=[v]
```

desired result:

```
{'AAPL': [1000], 'MSFT': [2000], 'TSLA': [1500]}
```

Later:

```
dictionary['AAPL'].append(1500)
```

You'll get:

```
{'AAPL': [1000, 1500], 'MSFT': [2000], 'TSLA': [1500]}
```